# C language strtok() specific element after delimiter

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

I have a series of strings each with letters, whitespace, numbers and $. What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the number(s) following the $? For example,

```
char s[50]= "I have $20 and 3 hours left to work.";
char t[50]= "He might have 4 left but does have $7.";
char u[50]= "$29 and 30 equal 59 dollars.";
/* I'm assuming strtok, since it makes the most sense to me */
```

Expected Output

```
20
 7
29
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Simple, use functions found in stdio.h and string.h. I'm guessing you haven't tried them yet. ( We won't write code for you. )

Comment: use `strchr` then `sscanf`.

Comment: What have you tried, and what result did you get?  Are you familiar with `sscanf()`?  What about `strtod()` or `strtol()`?  What type are the dollar amounts (integer or floating point)?  You could use `strchr()` or `strstr()` instead of `strtok()` — or, indeed, `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`.  Please create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) showing what you've done and showing the output you get and explaining what you don't understand about the results you are getting.

Comment: @this duh, I don't need for you to write code for me I just didn't know of the function that BLUEPIXY mentioned.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will take a look at all of those. Thanks and i will create a MCVE next time. Still new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Noobprogrammer Duh, read my comment, check those headers and documentation about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample by [strchr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) and [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(int val){
    printf("%d\n", val);
}

void get(const char *s, void (*callback)(int)){
    int value;
    while((s = strchr(s, '$')) != NULL){
        if(1==sscanf(++s, "%d", &value)){
            callback(value);
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    char s[50]= "I have $20 and 3 hours left to work.";
    char t[50]= "He might have 4 left but does have $7.";
    char u[50]= "$29 and 30 equal 59 dollars.";

    char *a[] = { s, t, u};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); ++i){
        get(a[i], print);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do it.

- Are you familiar with [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html)?  It could be used to do the job (but it isn't the simplest use of `sscanf()`).
- Are you familiar with
  [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) to convert a string to a `double`, or
  [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) to convert a string to a `long`?  Or their simpler counterparts 
  [`atof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html) and
  [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)?
- You could use [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) or 
  [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) instead of 
  [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html).  One disadvantage of `strtok()` is that it is destructive and non-informative — it zaps a delimiter and doesn't tell you which delimiter it found.  That means you can't use `strtok()` on string literals.
- You could also use [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) or
  [`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html) in place of `strchr()`.

Some combination of these — either `sscanf()` on its own, or one of the search functions plus `sscanf()`, or one of the search functions plus one of the conversion functions — can be made to do the job.

What do you want from strings such as these?

```
char nasty1[] = "Who writes $$ 20 and hopes to be OK?";
char nasty2[] = "He should have written one $, like $20.0000001";
char nasty3[] = "And $ 20 is too spaced out";
char nasty4[] = "Negative balances?  $-20 or -$20 or ($20) or $(20)?";
```

These may complicate your life.  You may also decide you don't need to worry about them.